# add timeout with http:request

Tags: erlang

I developed this function :

```
sms_sentByHttp(NumPhone,MsgReceived) ->

    NumPhoneTroncated = string:sub_string(NumPhone,2),
    {X1, X2, X3} = erlang:now(),
    Rand = random:uniform(9999),
    {{Y,M,D},{H,Mn,S}}=erlang:universaltime(),
    Ws_req_id = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p~p~p~p~p~p~p~p", [X3, Rand,Y,M,D,H,M,S])),
   Url = io_lib:format("http://localhost:7703/enda?msg=~s&from=~s&id=~s", [http_urii:encode(MsgReceived),http_urii:encode(NumPhoneTroncated),Ws_req_id]),

    case http:request(lists:flatten(Url)) of
        {ok , A} -> io:format("response sent\n");
        {error, B} -> io:format("response not sent\n ~w\n", [B])
    end.
```

Now I want to add the notion of timeout in the request and after for example 20 seconds. I want to display error from server

I tried with :

```
case http:request(lists:flatten(Url),[ {timeout,timer:seconds(20)}]) of
           {ok , A} -> io:format("response sent\n");
    {error, B} -> io:format("error from server\n ~w\n", [B])
        end.
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse/) as your HTTP client. It includes a timeout parameter in send_req/6 (and options for more fine-tuned timeouts). It's also generally more efficient than the inets library included by default.

Another option is [lhttpc](https://github.com/esl/lhttpc.git), but that apparently uses an environment variable for the timeout, which would be a problem if you need to change the timeout for certain requests.

EDIT:

[httpc:request/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-4) lets you specify a timeout as part of HTTPOptions, e.g.:

```
httpc:request(get, {URL, []}, [{timeout, timer:seconds(20)}], []).
```